# Buildozer building an Android Kivy app returns Command failed

Tags: android, python, ubuntu, kivy, buildozer

I'm creating an app in Kivy and tried to build it on a Buildozer virtual machine.
I followed [this tutorial](https://kivy.org/docs/guide/packaging-android.html) to set it up. Running the `buildozer android debug` command returns [this error](https://pastebin.com/yqGM3jhE).

I am not very experienced in Ubuntu so I've hit a wall.
sf_WKND is the shared folder where main.py is stored along with everything else. I haven't altered the buildozer.spec file except for log_level=2.
In dependencies I used the Android on Ubuntu 16.04 (64bit) commands. (Which I'm not sure is even correct, I don't have a clue which one to use so I figured the latest one)

Comment: I haven't seen an error like this before. Does it persist if you clean everything and try again? It might be worth trying in a non-shared directory in your home folder, although this should not really be important.

Comment: @inclement As it turns out, the shared directory was the case! I gave up on the app because I simply ran out of time (and couldn't figure out how to debug the crash-on-launch). No idea why, someone said something about symlinks, but moving the project directory to the VM did the trick. Also, I did try cleaning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone ever visits here having the same problem - all I had to do was move the project folder to the VM (I moved it to Desktop). Shared folders was somehow messing it up.